# Help to bypass password for sample projects of excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, passwords, vba

I am doing project in EXCEL VBA.
i am taking refernce of some projects made in excel vba.
But when I trid to open that excel sample projects, it ask me for password.
so how can bypass password for that excel project  so i can take refrence so that i can take refrence of sample.

Please help....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you unprotect the VBA macros for a macro-enabled workbook if you forgot the password?](http://superuser.com/questions/889097/how-do-you-unprotect-the-vba-macros-for-a-macro-enabled-workbook-if-you-forgot-t)

Answer (score 2):

the password was likely put in place to prevent copying of code. I would try Google for code that is freely available on the web relating to the sample project you are trying to recreate. Or ask a specific question here and see what you get.